# How to calculate the area inside a square defined by two radius lines from the inscribing circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm not big on maths, so I'll try to explain the question with a picture.

[image: ye]

Given a square of side a, what is the value of the green area x given by the two red lines that are separated by n rads, the first one being straight up at a 0° angle?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The circle is irrelevant.  Then half the side length of the square is one leg of the green right triangle. You know the central angle ($n$ radians) so simple trigonometry gives you the area of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be the length of the segment that the triangle $x$ and the square have in common as perimeter. Here is a fun theorem:
$$
\frac x{a^2}=\frac b{4a}
$$
In words, $x$ is as big part of the area of the square as $b$ is of the perimeter of the square. This also holds if the angle goes past a corner and $x$ is not a triangle any more.

We can find $b$ with a little trigonometry, and the answer follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let the radius be $1$, then one leg of the right angle in the green triangle is $\sqrt{2}/2$.  Use the intercept theorem to get $h$, the other leg, by
$$\frac{h}{\sin(n)}=\frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{\cos(n)}.$$

But, either way, the circle indeed is a red herring as @EthanBolker stated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define the function in terms of a parameter, say the angle $\theta$ (or $n$ in radians) from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$. The area to compute is the one of a triangle, call $b$ (base) the upper line in your figure, and $h$ (height) the vertical one. Then the area $X=bh/2$, where $h= r\: \cos(\pi /4)$ (constant) and the radius of the circle is $r=\sqrt{(a/2)²+(a/2)²}$, while the value of $b=h\: \tan(\theta)$. The computation of the other sides is equivalent, but remember to subtract $\pi/4$ when $\theta$ crosses $\pi/4$, $3\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ as the angle increases clockwise and add the area of the region that precedes..

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal of a square with sides $s$ is $\sqrt 2 s$ and as the diagonal of this square is $2r$, the side if this square is the solution to $\sqrt 2 s = 2r$ so $x = \frac {2}{\sqrt 2}r = \sqrt 2 r$.  So the distance from the center to the side "straight up" is $\frac {\sqrt 2}2 r$.

Now using trig identities, if we call the center of the square to the "straight up" side $x$ and edge of the green triangle (we are assuming $0< n \le \frac {\pi}4$) $y$ and the hypotenuse of the green triangle, $h$, we have

$x = h\cos n = \frac {\sqrt 2}2 r$.

$y = h\sin n$

$\frac yx = \tan n$

So $y = x\tan n= \frac {\sqrt 2}2 r\tan n$.

[image]

So the area of the green triangle is $\frac 12 xy = \frac 12 \cdot \frac {\sqrt 2}2 r\cdot \frac {\sqrt 2}2 r\tan n= \frac 14 r^2 \tan n$.

To solve for $n > \frac \pi 4$ just tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal of the square has a length of 2 radii. Hence the square's sides are length $\sqrt{2}$ radii, and the length of the vertical side of the triangle is $b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ radii. Since the triangle is right, we need only also find the length $h$ of the side that runs along the square to compute the area. We can do this using

$$\tan{n} = \frac{opp}{adj} = \frac{h}{b} = \sqrt{2}\ell.$$

Thus $h = \frac{\tan{n}}{\sqrt{2}}$ radii, so the area $x = \frac{1}{2}bh = \frac{\tan{n}}{4}$.